# Mathematically calculate the time complexity of all permutations of a string

Tags: summation, permutations, factorial, computational-complexity, programming

I am trying to mathematically analyze the complexity of the following code

```
void perm(String str){
  perm(str, "");
}

void perm(String str, String prefix){
   if(str.length() == 0){
       System.out.println(prefix);
   } else{
      for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
          String rem = str.substring(0, i) + 
                       str.substring(i + 1);
          perm(rem, prefix + str.charAt(i));
      }
   }
}
```

I saw [***this***](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexity-permutations-string/) website that explains the complexity using common sense but I want to try and solve this mathematically.

the equations I got are

(1) $T(n) = n(n+T(n-1)) = n^2 + nT(n-1)$

(2) $T(n) = n^2 + n(n-1)^2 + n(n-1)(n-2)^2 + ...  = \frac{nn!}{(n-1)!} + \frac{(n-1)n!}{(n-2)!} + \frac{(n-2)n!}{(n-3)!} + ... $

(3) $T(n) = n!(\frac{n}{(n-1)!} + \frac{n-1}{(n-2)!} + \frac{n-2}{(n-3)!} + ... + \frac{1}{0!})$

now I am stuck as I can't seem to find the value of the sum..

was the calculations right? got any tips for finding the value of $(\frac{n}{(n-1)!} + \frac{n-1}{(n-2)!} + \frac{n-2}{(n-3)!} + ... + \frac{1}{0!})$ ?

Thanks

Comment: 1 is the largest term in the series, the series has n terms thus the series is bounded above by `n`. So `(n/(n−1)!+n−1/(n−2)!+n−2/(n−3)!+...+1/0!) <= n` which should be good enough for asymptotic analysis

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac k{(k-1)!}x^k
&\simeq&
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac k{(k-1)!}x^k
\\
&=&\left(x\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\right)^2
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}
\\
&=&
\left(x\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\right)^2\left(\mathrm e^x-1\right)
\\
&=&\left(x^2+x\right)\mathrm e^x\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

Evaluating at $x=1$ yields $2\mathrm e$ as an estimate of your sum for large $n$.

Comment: Very interesting solution, but I think you copied down the problem incorrectly. It is not the $k$ that is incrementing; rather, it is the $-1$ that should be incrementing ($-1$, $-2$, …, $-n$).

Comment: @NetherGranite: I'm not sure what you mean. The term for $k=1$ corresponds to the right-most term in the sum, $\frac1{0!}$. The term for $k=n$ corresponds to the left-most term in the sum, $\frac n{(n-1)!}$. Where does it go wrong?

Comment: Oh, I see; you summed the terms backwards. My mistake.